# What is this HTTPRequest being used for?

Tags: javascript, http

```
function load_binary_resource(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, false);
    req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status != 200) {
        document.write("fail downloading loader");
        stop = 1
    };
    return req.responseText;
 }
  filestream = load_binary_resource("exec")
```

what is this doing and what would responseText contain?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which part of the code is causing confusion. Some elaboration would be helpful. However, here is a bit more detailed understanding of what this function is doing:

This function is sending an HTTP Request to a server that is reachable by traversing a path specified by the `url` parameter. `req.open` sets the method of your request to `GET`. It seems that you are sending no data with the request (as seen by `req.send(null)`). Finally, if the status of the request is anything other than `200` (which indicates that the request was OK), then this piece of code indicates a failure. You know the type of `req.responseText` to be of type `text/plain` since the line `req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined')` is included. Here is a resource to learn about `XMLHttpRequest` and the `overrideMimeType` function [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/overrideMimeType)

Comment: sorry, forgot this line to add:

    filestream=load_binary_resource("filename");

what would the file stream contain? and how can I establish the same output without doing an httpRequest?